# prompt in IE8 for secure pages produces altered layout

Tags: security

My Drupal 7 website looks fine in most browsers, but in IE8 I am getting the prompt:

> > "Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely? This webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS connection, which could compromise the security of the entire webpage."

Then a "Yes" or "No"

If the person selects "yes" they are presented with MOST of the page, but odd things like the sidebar CSS and body content don't display properly. Is this an issue with securepages module or something else? Initially I had secure pages turned off because I moved from a dev server (without SSL) to production. But even after turning it on, I get this message. I have:

- Cleared the cache
- Run the security review module (passes on all
  points)
- Ensured the core and all modules are up to date.

Also, I have the following lines in my settings.php file:

```
$base_url = 'https://my-website-here.org';
```

and

```
$conf['404_fast_paths_exclude'] = '/\/(?:styles)\//';
$conf['404_fast_paths'] = '/\.(?:txt|png|gif|jpe? g|css|js|ico|swf|flv|cgi|bat|pl|dll|exe|asp)$/i';
$conf['404_fast_html'] = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa-1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL "@path" was not found on this server.</p></body></html>';
```

Also, could jquery menu or Client-side adaptive image be causing a problem? The context module? These were all additions from the previous site that ran fine.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message you're getting in IE 8 is due to the fact that you're viewing your site through HTTPS, but some of your site's assets / resources are still being loaded through HTTP. If you look at the site in Chrome, you'll notice an icon to the right of the address bar which indicates the same warning about insecure content.

I would recommend going through all your templates / custom modules to make sure that any JS, CSS and iFrames (hope you have none of those heh) are all being served via HTTPs and not HTTP. Once nothing is being served via regular HTTP you shouldn't get that message anymore.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Alex. Indeed it turned out to be a link to htmlshiv in the theme that was hosted at an insecure url at Google. Overriding the theme html.tpl.php file fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement of the previous answer from AlexK and comment from Paul, I have applied this patch : https://drupal.org/node/1595062 in the 'sites/all/themes/omega/omega/templates/html.tpl.php' file and it solved this issue. 
You might need to know how to add a js file in your omega theme to make this work (https://drupal.org/node/1416128).